# Azure APIM and validate-azure-ad-token

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an AZURE APIM service that connects to Dynamics365 data to retrieve data.  This is done via an App Registration.

I would like to be able to allow users to connect to my APIM service using their pre-existing token from Active Directory.

I can retrieve a token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/####/oauth2/token

I am using validate-azure-ad-token to restrict access to my API.

```
    <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="####">
        <audiences>
            <audience>api://$$$$$$</audience>
        </audiences>
        <client-application-ids>
            <application-id>$$$$$$</application-id>
        </client-application-ids>
    </validate-azure-ad-token>
```

The above App Id has permissions to my back-end API that talks to Dynamics.

However, I keep getting back the following message.

{
"statusCode": 401,
"message": "Invalid Azure AD JWT"
}

Is there a way to troubleshooting these steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same policy to validate the Azure AD token and got the expected response.

***Policy I am using is***-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="{tenant-id}" output-token-variable-name="jwt">
            <audiences>
                <audience>api://{client-id}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <client-application-ids>
                <application-id>{client-id}</application-id>
            </client-application-ids>
        </validate-azure-ad-token>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

In order to test this policy in APIM, I have generated the bearer token in Postman as shown below-

You need to pass the ***resource*** value same as the ***audience*** value which you have used in the APIM policy.

[image]

Then, you will get the bearer token specific to that resource. Add this token to the request ***header***.

[image]
[image]

**Trace**-

[image]

Comment: Hi - I was able to do as you suggested - and validated the token for my app, which then allowed me to "validate" the token.  I'm also able to retrieve the token from that initial authentication.  However, when I try to use that token to connect to my app, this doesn't work - and I get a 401 unauthorized when trying to use this token to connect to my app (which should work)?  Or am I misunderstanding the value of this token?

Comment: Which app you are trying to connect using the token?

Comment: Given policy will work in the way, I have explained in my answer. If you have this policy defined in apim then you need to pass the bearer token while in invoking the apim url

Comment: I have two app registrations - the first one, is one tied to Dynamics365.  This app exposes its API to the second app (which is applying the validate-azure-ad-token).

Comment: If you want to invoke dynamic365 urls then you need to generate the token for this resource

Comment: Hey - I wrote this up as a new question - thank you for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78088254/pass-ad-token-through-azure-apim-to-dynamics-web-api-service